# Scala convert List with unknown length to Tuple so pass it to Slick map clause

Tags: scala, list, tuples, slick

I have `List` in scala code which e.g i can receive from the specific method, and length of this list can vary from time to time, my target is converting this `List` to `Tuple` with same count of element:

```
val lst = someComputationHere()
val tupleLst = lstToTuple(lst)
```

**clarification**

```
//if lst.length = 2 --> Tuple2
//if lst.length = 3 --> Tuple3
//if lst.length = 4 --> Tuple4
...............

//if lst.length = N --> TupleN
and so on
```

p.s. I prefer don't use the reflection for solving this problem

**UPD**
My target is pass list with properties described above, to `Slick` `map clause`. Let's consider the next code snapshot:

```
query.map{ p=> (p.value1, p.value2, ... , p.valueN)}
```

Amount of this value is dinamic and i introduced this `values` to list:

```
  val lst = someComputationHere()
    val tuples = toTuples(lst)//Problem is here
    query.map{_ => tuples}
```

**Problem description**:  `query.map{}` - doen't pass the list, and as consequance, i must convert `lst` with changeable length N to `Tuple` with N elements

Comment: For what purpose you'd do that?

Comment: Common super-type of various tuples would be `Product`. I.e. `val tupleLst: Product = ???` That gives you an untyped iterator. What do you expect to do with that?

Comment: @ pedrofurla I need for this conversion so put `List` on place of `Tuple` in map clause of `Slick` so fetch parameters with dynamically changeable amount of them. But it doesn't matter to Slick, let's consider this problem in terms of Scala code only without any third part libraries.

Comment: What do you do with the tuples? If you just pass them straight to a family of functions `TupleN => SomeType` then you can just create a function `List[T] => SomeType` by matching on the list and dispatching the relevant tuple immediately based on the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Slick, but if it only handles tuples it seems like a bad design choice for me. Even in Scala 2.12 there are no predefined types for tuples of arity greater than 22, although Scala will create them synthetically. So your best option is one big pattern match including all arities you need to support:

```
def toTuple[A](lst: List[A]): Product = lst match {
  case _1 :: Nil             => Tuple1(_1)
  case _1 :: _2 :: Nil       => Tuple2(_1, _2)
  case _1 :: _2 :: _3 :: Nil => Tuple3(_1, _2, _3)
  ...
}
```

Comment: if i need to take exactly `TupleN` instead of `Product` type, i couldn't cast `Product` to `TupleN` in your `toTuple` implementation.

Comment: There is no such thing as `TupleN`

Comment: @pacman You're trying to take something defined at runtime and enforce upon it something that can only be defined at compile time. This is the best solution you can hope to achieve.

Comment: @0__ I meant the general case, where N is a length of lst

Comment: @pacman You can know N only at runtime (this is what wheaties is saying). List doesn't encode its length in the type. So you cannot make a type from the length. If you can change List for a type that encodes length, you might be more lucky. I believe the Shapeless library has something like this. I still believe your scenario is ill formulated. Either Slick accepts any tuple (then it would probably ask for a Product), or it asks for one particular tuple (then you only need to verify the list length).

Comment: @0__  i looked on `shapeless` library, it have same "limitations" regard the length of list in compile time. p.s. Design of `Slick` firmly upset me in a force that they don't handle list in map clause.

Comment: @pacman I think you should reformulate the question, add the `slick` tag and show how you are planning to pass `tupleLst` to Slick API.

Answer (score 0):

In generally you can't do this because tuple access methods `_1`, `_2` etc have compile time checks (list size is undefined in compile time). But all tuples realises Product trait, where you can get element by its order:

```
(1, 2, 3).productElement(2) // returns 2
```

You can try to write method with next signature (maybe using macros)

```
List[T] => Product
```

method will be return `TupleN` where N is list size. For example, very primitive realisation:

```
list.length match {
  case 1 => (list(0))
  case 2 => (list(0), list(1))
  ...
  case 22 => (list(0), list(1), ... ,list(21))
  case _ => throw some exception...
}
```

After it in runtime you can try to cast your product to concrete TupleN type. But all this seems very dirty.